# Calculating funding thermometer

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I have used an example courtesy of CodePen (https://codepen.io/developer007/pen/NNdBQw?page=3) which I have turned into a horizontal thermometer.

However, I am stumped when trying to calculate the maths statement in the javascript file. I want to have a goal of $111,000 but the current file only calculates to 1000.

I also can't make the progress amount line up with the progress bar...

```
 // JavaScript Document
 function thermometer(goalAmount, progressAmount, animate) {
 "use strict";
 var $thermo = $("#thermometer"),
    $progress = $(".progress", $thermo),
    $goal = $(".goal", $thermo),
    percentageAmount;

 goalAmount = goalAmount || parseFloat($goal.text()),
 progressAmount = progressAmount || parseFloat($progress.text()),
 percentageAmount = Math.min(Math.round(progressAmount / goalAmount * 
 1000) / 10, 100); //make sure we have 1 decimal point

 $goal.find(".amount").text();
 $progress.find(".amount").text();

 $progress.find(".amount").hide();
 if (animate !== false) {
    $progress.animate({
        "width": percentageAmount + "%"
    }, 1200, function () {
        $(this).find(".amount").fadeIn(200);
    });
 } else {
    $progress.css({
        "width": percentageAmount + "%"
    });
    $progress.find(".amount").fadeIn(200);
 }
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {

 thermometer();

 });
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Please click `<>` and post a [mcve] - if the `$goal.text()` returns 100000, I assume it should work, if not then not. JS does not like `100,000`  - you need 100000 or replace "," with nothing

Comment: Since you aren't passing `goalAmount` into the function, what is the content of `$(".goal", $thermo).text()`?

Comment: just change the values in HTML: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmNXzR?page=3

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the values being passed into the JQuery function to the goal amount you want and the progress you want. Example: I moved the goal to 111,000$ and set the progress to 69908$ here.

```
<div id="thermometer">
            <div class="track">
                <div class="goal">
                    <div class="amount" id="goalAmount">111000$</div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress"">
                    <div style="display: block;" class="amount" id="progessAmount">69908$</div>
                </div>
        <div class="bulb"><div class="inner-bulb"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvzmbm?page=3